# CredSSP error while connecting to Hyper-V Server 2016 VM

Tags: networking, hyper-v, credssp

I'm using a domain laptop to remotely manage a bunch of Hyper-V Server 2016, also joined to this domain. But since a recent domain change, I came across an issue with one server.

I can open Hyper-V manager, add the faulty server and get the list of VMs. Even the preview of the VM screen is showing when it's running.

But whenever I try connecting to a VM, I get the error with CredSSP stating (approximative translation from French, see exact error message [here](https://www.tech2tech.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/RDC_CredSSP.png)):

"An authentication error occured, requested function cannot be provided" blablabla.

I already tried to add the registry key on the Hyper-V Server:

`reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\CredSSP\Parameters /f /v AllowEncryptionOracle /t REG_DWORD /d 2`

But it's still not working.

Since I'm in a domain, I looked at the GPO, but the "Encryption Oracle Remediation" does not show in the GPO manager.

Strange thing, I can connect and manage VMs without any problem on another server also running Hyper-V Server 2016 (those 2 servers are in a different subnet).

The VMs are running Ubuntu Server 20.04 if it matters.

Any idea on how to fix this please?

**EDIT:** both servers are up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It wasn't related to the Hyper-V Servers, but to the old Windows 10 laptop I use to manage the servers.

I added the key in the registry:

`reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\CredSSP\Parameters /f /v AllowEncryptionOracle /t REG_DWORD /d 2`

and it worked like a charm.

Sorry for disturbing...